# Is the directory structure used in Unix file system a directed acyclic graph?

Tags: linux, unix, graph, filesystems

I have gone through some materials available on the web regarding the unix file system but I couldn't get any proper answer.In some materials it is mentioned that the directory structure used in unix file system has a hierarchical directory structure whereas in some others it has been mentioned that actually it's a directed acyclic graph due to the presence of hard links.It is obviously hierarchical but DAG will be a better term to describe it.Can anyone explain whether it is really a DAG or hierarchical or tree structured?

Comment: exactly *which* filesystem are we talking about here?

Comment: Not about any particular file system,it's just about the Unix file system which we come across when we read out the first few chapters of any book on the Unix OS.Anyway I have got my answer in the book 'Operating system concepts' written by Silberchatz,Galvin.The answer is that the Unix file system directory structure is a DAG due to the presence of hardlinks which makes sharing of files and subdirectories among different directories possible.

Answer (score 3):

It's a limited type of directed graph. If we leave aside symbolic links for a moment, then the *directory* structure of the filesystem is a tree, because directories cannot be hard-linked. The joint structure of directories and files is a type of restricted DAG, because the things at the leaves, i.e. the directory entries, may be hard links.

If symbolic links are taken into account, then the structure is a general graph, but because symlinks can always be recognized as such, cycles can be broken simply by treating links as a special type of file (i.e. use `lstat` instead of `stat`).